# A good way to populate triangle of numbers into tree data structure

Tags: c#, data-structures, graph, binary-tree

I have a following data in my input file:

```
1
3 2
5 6 4
7 9 8 10
```

The relationship between the data is the following:

3 and 2 are children of 1, and 3 has children 5, 6 while 2 has children 6 and 4.

So it is a triangle-based structure, like a pyramid.

I have written a class called *Tree* in my code, and tree has a an object of class *TriangleNode* for the tree root:

```
public class TriangleNode { 
    public int data; 
    public TriangleNode leftChild;
    public TriangleNode rightChild;

    public Node(int item) 
    { 
        data = item; 
        leftChild = null;
        rightChild = null;
    } 
}
```

What I need to do specifically, is to read the triangle and populate all the data into my own custom structure which is described above. It would be good not to duplicate objects, so if two parents share a child in a triangle do something like this (maybe). But I need to do this for a whole file.

```
tree.node.left.right = new TriangleNode(2);
tree.node.right.left = tree.node.left.right;
```

Maybe someone could help me with a way to populate my structure with a data efficiently? I looked here and didn't find a good way to do this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "classical triangle based structure" - can you please provide some links that explain that? This sentence "tree structure ... if two parents *share a child*..." makes it even more confusing - that can't be a tree...

Comment: Maybe I was not very exact here, maybe a word simple would be more appropriate. What I meant was a pyramid made out of numbers with child relationships. Edited the description.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I think he means something akin to Pascal's triangle, where (in row 2 for example) the left 1 is a parent of 1  and 2, and the right 1 is a parent of 2 and 1.

Comment: Yes, in my own example 3 has children 5, 6 and 2 has children 6, 4. I mentioned the tree structure not to confuse, but to emphasize I need to populate this data into my binary structure which I have described above.

Comment: @preferred_anon but they ask for [tree structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29) - which simply won't be tree if children are shared... Very unclear what actual requirement is.

Comment: "mentioned the tree structure not to confuse," -  mentioning something that definitely not what you want is not making things any more clear... [edit] post after you read definition of the tree and inline all your comments.

Comment: Alexei, can you emphasize what exactly is unclear? I wrote that I have a pyramid of numbers where each has two children. And I also wrote that I need to read this data and populate into my own created btree structure which is also described above. For me it seems crystal clear what needs to be done and in the final result a populated structure described above is what I would need. Please ask a specific question so I could answer.

Comment: @jburnham If two nodes share a parent, then it's not a tree. I mentioned Pascal's triangle earlier - that graph is not a tree. You could *make* it a tree, by duplicating the shared children. But you explicitly say "it would be better not to duplicate objects. So you have to pick whether you want to make a tree (or instead some weaker idea), or to duplicate elements. Please indicate which one in your question.

Comment: My idea was to use the structure which I have described above, and after the file is read, populate it with data, but don't duplicate. Like I wrote in the above, for a shared child create it for tree.left.left = new TriangleNode(2), for example and then tree.left.right = tree.left.right, not creation a duplicate node. But I am struggling to create a code which would (maybe recursively) perform this for a whole triangle. That is the essence of my request. But if you could suggest a better structure and solution, I would be grateful to see it.

Comment: if i was you, i would focus on how to create a tree structure.. once you have that, you can tweak it to for-fill this requirement., aka it will probably take you a while to get a simple tree working ..http://csharphelper.com/blog/2015/02/make-a-generic-treenode-class-in-c-part-1/ that link should help

Comment: @Seabizkit do you mean that my current structure will not suffice for this task? Is something essential missing? Thanks for the link.

Comment: your links need a way of knowing who is the parent.... out side of their id, so each node need to know its parent. now knowing this you can add this to the data structure....

Answer (score 0):

Not only would it be good not to duplicate objects, but it's most probably a must too, because if one of these objects changed somehow, then you would have to ensure the other one changed too.

So I would suggest keeping a collection of data and referring to its members from your TriangleNode class, instead of creating 2 separate identical objects (one for each parent in two different parent nodes).

Comment: Yes, this is my general idea. Could you help with the solution how this could be done?

Comment: That's a rather broad question and depends a *lot* on how parent knows what its children are, how you're reading that input file, what characteristics are your objects recognized by, are they unique, etc. If it is indeed integers that you store in your funky tree, and they are unique as your example seems to imply, then you could use that very integer as a key in the Dictionary<key/TriangleNode> collection. Than the TriangleNode would have only 2 members - left and right child. Data itself is already the 'key'.

Comment: Can't type everything in one comment... Anyway, if it is not unique integers, then skip the optimization and have, for example, natural numbers 0, 1, 2, 3... as your keys, and TriangleNode objects as values (where your 'data' is a third member of the node)